# Best way to replace value of attribute

Tags: php, html

I am working on a script that fetches pictures from iTunes. Unfortunately the image element does not display the image out of the box, it uses a placeholder image, with the actual image url stored in another attribute of the image element.

Example:

```
<img width="100" height="100" src-swap="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/jfd25732df/cover100x100.jpeg" class="artwork" src="https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/9E1F/frameworks/images/p.png" />

<img width="100" height="100" src-swap="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/h63qz8uil5/cover100x100.jpeg" class="artwork" src="https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/9E1F/frameworks/images/p.png" />

<img width="100" height="100" src-swap="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/h8534edcbn/cover100x100.jpeg" class="artwork" src="https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/9E1F/frameworks/images/p.png" />
```

I had a look at preg_match_all, but didn't get anywhere really, mainly because the src-swap attribute has a different value on every image.

My entire script uses [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape the pictures. There might be a built in way to replace attributes, but all my attempts lead to nowhere.

All I am looking for is the most efficient way to replace the src attribute with the swap-src attribute of each image.

Comment: You can make this with jQuery or Vanilla js

Comment: If you have the DOM parser you're on the right track. I believe you're looking for `setAttribute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
$string = '<img width="100" height="100" src-swap="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/jfd25732df/cover100x100.jpeg" class="artwork" src="https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/9E1F/frameworks/images/p.png" />';

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

function swapSource($string){
    $srcswap = get_string_between($string, "src-swap=\"", "\" class");
    $src = get_string_between($string, "src=\"", "\"");

    return str_replace($src,$srcswap,$string);
}

echo swapSource($string);
```

And just call the swapSource() function for each image.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this server side, as indicated by the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should work.

[Heres a quick example.](https://ideone.com/xkbRDd)

```
$image = '<img width="100" height="100" src-swap="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/jfd25732df/cover100x100.jpeg" class="artwork" src="https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/9E1F/frameworks/images/p.png" />';
$replace = preg_replace('/src-swap="(.*?)"(.*?)src="(.*?)"/', 'src-swap="$1"$2src="$1"', $image);

echo ($replace);
```

Alternatively, this can be done [client side using Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/8buggc0q/). Here is a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) example. Watch out though, `src-swap` is not a valid attribute. If you are using the custom data attributes, [it should be `data-src-swap`](https://jsfiddle.net/eb7y3qhv/).

```
$("img").each(function() {
    var swap = $(this).attr("src-swap");
    $(this).attr("src", swap);
    // alert($(this).attr("src")); 
});
```